# How to have a div expand to left and right?

Tags: css

I have a div with a min and max width.

**CSS**

```
#box{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 100px;
    min-width: 180px;
    max-width: 320px;
    height: 180px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5QdFS/

When I type something long into the box it expands to the right. Is it possible to make the box expand to both the left and right evenly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a container with `text-align:center;` like so:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="photo"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
    text-align: center;    
}
#photo{
    min-width: 180px;
    max-width: 320px;
    height: 180px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

**[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5QdFS/4/)**

Comment: you have not set position: absolute; and top , left values could you do by setting these?

Comment: +1 But i have a question. Why text-align ? It is actually setting the alignment of a div not text content. ?

Comment: @C-Link You can't set the left value if you want to expand both ways as you actually mentioned in your answer, you can use margin-top to set the top value.

Comment: @VivekSadh Text-align property also affects inline-block elements, that's why I used `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 2):

You have set left value to 100 pixels which could not let you expand left and right evenly.

**Edit**

If you don't need absolute position then you could do this by setting `margin: 0 auto;` and `display: table;` to your div.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5QdFS/6/)